# ADOX or SQL DDL

Tags: c#, ddl, adox

I tried two method to create tables inside a new  Ms Access database generated by ADOX catalog class. The first method is using ADOX classes and Properties  to create columns and tables and eventually add them to Database at the same time of database creation. The second method is using an OleDbConnection class and execute SQL DDL commands two create Tables inside the empty database.

For me, both methods works fine but I really need to know which method is implementing better in reality?

Thanks

Comment: what do u mean define? from the point of programming and implementing the methods, which one is better?

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"